# Error on client side when using iBM Bluemix tone analyzer token fetched on server side

Tags: javascript, ajax, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, tone-analyzer

I've already gotten a token on the server side and stored it in a cookie, but I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting an error when I query the api with that token.

Here's the jQuery ajax request I'm sending:

```
$.ajax({
     url:'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone',
         data:{
            'X-Watson-Authorization-Token':readCookie('token'),
            'text':input,
            'version':'v3',
            'version_date':'2016-05-19'
        },
        dataType:'jsonp',
        contentType:'application/json',
        method:'GET',
        success:function(tone){
            console.log(tone);
        }
    });
```

If I don't use `dataType:jsonp`, I get a no access control-origin error. When I don't use `contentType:application/json` or use `contentType:application/javascript`, I get a login dialog when the api is queried asking for a username and password. But I shouldn't have to pass the username and password now that I've got a token. And when I run it this way, with both dataType and contentType, I get a 400 error bad request.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? The documentation says I can use the token on the client side., but I have to fetch it on the server side.

UPDATE:

As per advice, I am not accessing the server side code through a jquery ajax call of a separate php file. I am able to get the token, but when I pass it to the api call to the tone analyzer, I get a 400 error. Regardless if I decodeURI the token or not.

Here is my jquery:

```
$.when($.ajax({
    url:'watsonToken.php',
    type:'GET',
})).done(function(token){
    console.log('watsonToken, lasts 1 hour: ', decodeURI(token));
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone',
        type:'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify({
            'body':input,
            'version':'2016-05-19'
        }),
        contentType:'application/json',
        headers:{
            'X-Watson-Authorization-Token':decodeURI(token)
        },
        success:function(tone){
            console.log(tone);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.error('Error: Couldn\'t use token: ', error);
        }
    });
}).fail(function(){
    console.error('Error: Couldn\'t fetch watson token');
});
```

And the watsonToken.php file that gets the token:

```
<?php
$accessWatsonToken = curl_init();
$params=http_build_query(array('url' =>     'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone'));
curl_setopt($accessWatsonToken, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?$params");
curl_setopt($accessWatsonToken, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($accessWatsonToken, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username':password');
print curl_exec($accessWatsonToken);
curl_close($accessWatsonToken);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to put `X-Watson-Authorization-Token` as a body param when it should be a header and `version` should be a query param. Also in your data field for your JQuery rest call you are stringifying an object that is already stringified and in the headers you are decoding the token response that does not need to be decoded

You can find out more information about how to create calls to the Watson tone analyzer service [here](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/tone-analyzer/api/v3/?curl#post-tone)

EDIT: Here is a full example using PHP.

**index.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Watson Tone Analyzer Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>This is an example of client side call to Watson Tone analyzer service using an authorization token.</h2>
    <div id="myoutput"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
analyze();

function analyze(){
  $.ajax({
       url:'/get-token.php',
          type:'GET',
          success:function(token){
              callToneAnalyzer(token);
          },
          error: function(err) {
              console.error(err);
          }
      });
}

function callToneAnalyzer(token) {
  $.ajax({
       url:'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2016-05-19',
          type:'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify({text: "this is my sample text"}),
          contentType: 'application/json',
          headers: {
            'X-Watson-Authorization-Token': token
          },
          success:function(tone){
              $("#myoutput").text(JSON.stringify(tone));
          },
          error: function(err) {
              $("#myoutput").text(JSON.stringify(err));
          }
      });
}
</script>
```

**get-token.php**

```
<?php
// Send a http request using curl
function getToken(){
     $username='YOUR-TONE-ANALYZER-USERNAME';
     $password='YOUR-TONE-ANALYZER-PASSWORD';
     $URL='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api';

     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

     $result=curl_exec ($ch);
     curl_close ($ch);
     return $result;
}
echo getToken();
?>
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that's how you pass headers. But now I get a 403 error: `MLHttpRequest cannot load https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://domaincom' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.`

Comment: are you running this from localhost or somewhere else? Did you try an exact copy of the code above with the exception of using your token?

Comment: I used this exact code and I'm running this on an actual server, online

Comment: Okay I was able to run that locally and up on a server online. This made me think your token could be the problem. So I put a bad token into my call and got the same access control error response back as you posted. Please recheck the token you are providing in the ajax request to make sure its correct, that will fix this issue

Comment: You can view more information about how to obtain the token correctly from here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-tokens.shtml#program or if you are using Node.js there is a SDK to help make this a lot easier, which is what I used. Information for that is here https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk#authorization

Comment: That's the resource I used, I'm getting the token with php and immediately storing it inside a cookie. Do I have to encode it or turn it to json?

Comment: I create a new instance of the tone analyser service, got new credentials, changed the PHP so it doesn't store the token in a cookie, but as a param in the URL, then in the js, I decode it and run it with your exact code, but am now getting a 401 ( Processed ) error failed to load resource. The token api is not supposed to be able to give a bad token, if I am running the wrong code it returns an error. Any ideas?

Comment: Your javascript should call your php server through a REST call and ask for the token. Your server should access the watson token service and ask for a token. Then the php server will return the token in the response of the call you just made. Then your client (using javascript) should take that token form the php servers response and use it for the call to the watson tone service. If you are doing all of that then you should be good to go. You shouldn't need to "decode" the token at all

Comment: I am doing exactly that now and still getting a 400 error, but not the access-control header error. I've updated my question with the jquery and php that I am using.

Comment: I added a full php example in my answer. That should help you understand what went wrong and get you moving forward.