# How to enable CORS in Bluemix Conversation

Tags: cors, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Is it possible to enable CORS in an IBM Bluemix Conversation service?

This is to allow the api to be called in client-side javascript and prevent cross-origin errors.

Comment: Update - we actually went a different approach, using php to make the calls and send back the responses so didn't need to enable CORS etc.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the [Conversation API doc](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#authentication) it does look possible.

> Applications can also use tokens to establish authenticated communications with Watson services without embedding their service credentials in every call. You write an authentication proxy in Bluemix to obtain a token for your client application, which can then use the token to call the service directly. You use your service credentials to obtain a token for that service...

There is one extra step. You will have to use the [Authorization Service](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-tokens.shtml) to generate a watson auth token on your server side.

Then you can have your client side use that token either with the header: `X-Watson-Authorization-Token` or as a query param with the key named `watson-token` to make requests directly to the conversation service.

The answer I provided [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262937/error-on-client-side-when-using-ibm-bluemix-tone-analyzer-token-fetched-on-serve/40266889#40266889) may also help you as it has some working sample code for the Watson Tone Analyzer Service that does what I mentioned above with a php server used to generate the Watson auth token. You will have to substitute the conversation urls in place of the Tone Analyzer ones.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simpler way to enable CORS for any kind of service interface. Simply add the domain you want to allow CORS in the response headers.
You may want to allow requests coming from all origins, so you can also generate such header dynamically:

```
app.post('/api/conversation', function(request, response) {
    var text = request.body.text;

    //this is the point you prepare for CORS
    var origin = request.headers.origin;
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    //and you have just solved the CORS issue

    conversation.message({
        workspace_id: 'your-conversation-workspace-id-here',
        input: {'text': text},
        context: {}
    },
    function(err, resp) {
        if (err){
            response.sendStatus(500);
        }else{
            response.write(JSON.stringify(resp));
            response.end();
        }
    });
});
```